# PHP - CSV to MySQL to frontend, and back to CSV, best encoding / string function practices?

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, fgetcsv

I have a scenario where CSV files are being used to maintain data (products) in a MySQL database. Basically the steps that the client follows to maintain products is as follows:

- Adds items to the CSV file in predefined columns
- Uploads the CSV in backend
- PHP script iterates over CSV data
- Data is validated / cleaned and sent to MySQL database

Same applies in reverse when the client edits, adds or removes items, however this can also be done straight from the backend. I have had issues with certain characters not showing properly in the database or in the downloaded spreadsheet, so my question is:

Generally, what is a good set of encoding or string functions to apply to the data when adding and retrieving it in the form of a CSV file? My MySQL connection encoding is UTF-8, however I have tried saving the CSV file with a UTF-8 character set, but it seems Excel automatically applies the default Windows-1252 encoding to it, breaking all ym UTF-8 characters.

Applications like Open Office.org prompt you for the import character set, and whe set to Unicode UTF-8 it displays fine. Obviously one cannot rely on the client always using Excel or Open Office, so what is a good solution for PC / CSV >  MySQL > back to PC / CSV work?

All suggestions welcomed and appreciated.

Simon

Comment: Suggest having a read of this article to get started - http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @David - Thank you, I have read that article - it is brilliant. I am more after a process to follow in the CSV > MySQL and back process. Thank you

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the datamapper design pattern then.

Comment: @David - What exactly is that and how could it help me?

Comment: It is a generalised solution for mapping data between two sources, in your case a CSV file and a database. I've pulled up this article on it, a quick googling will find you more. http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Implementing-the-Data-Mapper-Design-Pattern-in-PHP-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to answer after the comments. Have a good understanding of `http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html` and look at implementing a datamapper pattern, example article about it here - `http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Implementing-the-Data-Mapper-Design-Pattern-in-PHP-5`.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you are trying to open, edit, and save CSV files using Excel.
This is generally a bad idea [for a whole range of reasons](http://theonemanitdepartment.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/the-absolute-minimum-everyone-working-with-data-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-file-types-encoding-delimiters-and-data-types-no-excuses/), including the fact that it does not allow you to specify the details of a csv file you export to.

A fail-safe, yet more cumbersome method might be to load the data into Access instead, and work with the data there. Access allows 'export to text file' using more advanced settings, like encoding and delimiter.

Comment: that is not what I wanted to do, no. As the question states, I was exporting data from a range of MySQL tables (programmatically) for opening in any spreadsheet application such as MS Excel, Apache Open Office etc. David Gillen's link helped a lot back then (3 years ago!) and I now have a full understanding of character sets and how to encode, decode and convert them. I appreciate your input, thank you.